# How to change color of selected row on onmousedown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-color, onmousedown

I am trying to change the color of the selected row from a table on a `onmousedown` event and `reset` all others (or keep them the same) . Only one row can be `red` at a time while all others are `green`.

What I have tried:

```js
function HighLight(id) {
  var rows = $('#tbl > tbody > tr').each(function(elem) {
    elem.style.background = 'green';
  })
  var tr = document.getElementById(id);
  tr.style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <tr id="tr1" style="background-color:aquamarine" onmousedown="Highlight(e)">
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2" style="background-color:aquamarine" onmousedown="Highlight(e)">
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3" style="background-color:aquamarine" onmousedown="Highlight(e)">
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Ideally I would like to store the `old` selected row so that I won't reset all others at each new selection, but in case I can't reset all would do it.

**P.S** I need to make due with the `id` that i am provided.I am using `interop` so the id is coming from the exterior. All my `tr` have that method injected in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function name is wrong its `Highlight` not `HighLight`

To pass the id of the element on function call you cannot just pass any variable(**e in your case**). Use `this.getAttribute('id')` to get the id.

In the `each()` the argument `elem represented the index` of the element and not the element itself. Introduce another argument for index.

```js
function Highlight(id) {
  var rows = $('#tbl > tbody > tr').each(function(i,elem) {
    elem.style.background = 'green';
  })
  var tr = document.getElementById(id);
  tr.style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <tr id="tr1" style="background-color:aquamarine" onmousedown="Highlight(this.getAttribute('id'))">
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2" style="background-color:aquamarine" onmousedown="Highlight(this.getAttribute('id'))">
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3" style="background-color:aquamarine" onmousedown="Highlight(this.getAttribute('id'))">
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick example on how can you do that.

```js
$("table tr").on('click', function(){
  $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
  $(this).addClass("highlighted");
});
```

```css
table tr {
  background: green;
}
table tr.highlighted {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3">
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Here is how it works:

1. It binds a `click` event to every row in the table (`tr`),
2. Every time you click on a row, all elements that has a class called `highlighted` loose it and the row that you clicked gets the class `highlighted`,

In css you can change the default background color for all rows and the color after highlighting.

If you don't want to use a css, here is similar function but instead of adding and removing class it does the same with the inline css property.

```js
$("table tr").on('click', function(){
  $("table tr").css("background", "green");
  $(this).css("background", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <tr id="tr1" style="background: green;">
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2" style="background: green;">
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3" style="background: green;">
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I do not recommend the second solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can have two css classes; one for selected row and other for remaining rows.
On click of the row, you can add the "selected" class to that row.

```js
$("#tbl tr").click(function(){
 
 var $this = $(this);
 //remove the previous row selection, if any
 $("#tbl tr.selected").removeClass("selected");
 //add selected class to the current row
 $this.addClass("selected");

});
```

```css
#tbl tr{
background-color: aquamarine;
}

#tbl tr.selected{
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbl">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2" >
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3" >
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And when you say `this` how does it know to refer to a `tr` or a `td` ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian - depends on the click handler -> here the click is registered for `tr` -> `$("#tbl tr").click`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.by using class you can carry out other operations

```js
$("#tbl").on("click", "tr", function() {
  $(' tr').removeClass("Red")

  $(this).addClass("Red")
});
```

```css
.Red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3">
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- JS is case sensitive, so `Highlight` and `HighLight` (capital L) is not the same. I renamed the `HighLight` function to `Highlight` (lowercase l)
- Use parameter `this` on function call in event handler attribute. This hands over the HTML element of the event handler attribute over to the event handler function (`Highlight` in your case)
- Callback function of jQuery's [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method has the `index` as a first parameter and the element as second

This makes your code work

```js
function Highlight(tr) {
  var rows = $('#tbl > tbody > tr').each(function(index, elem) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  })
  tr.style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbl">
  <tr id="tr1" style="background-color:aquamarine" onmousedown="Highlight(this)">
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2" style="background-color:aquamarine" onmousedown="Highlight(this)">
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3" style="background-color:aquamarine" onmousedown="Highlight(this)">
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

There are some more things you can do to enhance your code

1. Don't use style in your JS code, but set classes for CSS
2. Don't use HTML `onmousedown` attributes, but JS `addEventListeners`
3. Replace jQuery code with VanillaJS

```js
console.clear()
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#tbl > tbody > tr');
for (row of rows) {
  row.addEventListener('mousedown', Highlight)
}

function Highlight(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const tr = this
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#tbl > tbody > tr');
  for (row of rows) {
    row.classList.remove('highlight')
    row.classList.add('highlight-siblings')
  }
  tr.classList.remove('highlight-siblings')
  tr.classList.add('highlight')
}
```

```css
/* 1. */
tr {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
tr.highlight-siblings{
  background-color: green;
}
tr.highlight{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
    <td>
      v1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
    <td>
      v2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
    <td>
      v3
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```